# Interfacing sensors to NVIDIA Jetson Nano

Tags: iot, sensors, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have 8 sensors and I need your opinion on which is better: interface all sensors directly to nvidia Jetson Nano or interface them to another microcontroller board like arduino or esp32 then send their data with serial port to th Jetson Nano for data analysis and action decision ? and why ?
Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

On the Jetson, you have the GPIO pins, the I2C buses and you can use an Arduino as a sub-processor.
The GPIO is convenient but requires the Jetson to do all the work.
The I2C bus is common and many sensors are available and can be daisy chained.  The sensor needs an I2C interface.
The Arduino just needs a USB port and can offload processing.  They also come in many different flavors/sizes with plenty of interface choices for different sensors.
Would need to know more about your sensors to make the call.